# How to access an object created inside a module in julia

Tags: julia

I would like to access a dataframe created within a function within a module in julia.

```
module mymodule
df = DataFrame()
function trial(x)
    df = DataFrame(A = [x, 2], B = [4, 5])
    push!(df, [3 6])
end
end
```

My code in my other file is:

```
mymodule.trial(10)
```

I'm hoping to access the new `df` object, but I get nothing.
I've read the scoping section exhaustively, exporting, and structs. I'm needing to be pointed in the right direction.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this was rather simple.
I just needed to create an object:
`df = mymodule.trial(10)` allowed me to access the dataframe object.

Comment: Are you sure the code does what you want? On the one hand, you are returning the local instance of `DataFrame` from the function `trial` (via implicit return), but on the other hand you also create a global variable `df` in the module that is just an empty `DataFrame` (which you never use). You could just delete the global version, but I don't know what your goal is.